# ServerSocket accept method - How can I down cast to a subclass type?

Tags: java, sockets, classcastexception

I have a class ClientSocket that extends class Socket. The reason I extend class Socket, is that I want to include a String clientId that uniquely identifies a client on the other side of the socket. I also have a method called 'getClientId' that returns the clientId.

I have a ServerSocket instance running on my server that accepts socket connections like so:

```
public Socket acceptNextConnection() throws IOException {
    Socket socket = serverSocket.accept();

    // put the client socket into the map
    ClientSocket clientSocket = (ClientSocket) socket;
    clientConnections.put(clientSocket.getClientId(), clientSocket);

    return clientSocket;
}
```

As you can see, my cast here is incorrect as a Socket instance IS NOT a ClientSocket instance and so I get a class cast exception, as I expected. As is evident in the code, I want to call 'getClientId' on class ClientSocket. However I can't do this because the serverSocket.accept method returns a Socket object at runtime, not a ClientSocket. My question is, is there a way around this? If not, is there a neater way of doing what I want, which is being able to uniquely identify a socket that is bound to a client? An ip address can be subject to change.

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can have a ServerClientSocket which return a ClientSocket from accept. Something like

```
public class ServerClientSocket extends ServerSocket {
  public ClientSocket accept() throws IOException {
  if (isClosed())
    throw new SocketException("Socket is closed");
  if (!isBound())
    throw new SocketException("Socket is not bound yet");
  ClientSocket s = new ClientSocket((SocketImpl) null);
  implAccept(s);
  return s;
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi Peter. Thanks for the reply. I was thinking this. Is this a safe option? I'm aware that 'accept' can throw some exceptions, but am I covering all avenues here by taking the above approach? Also, I'm not sure I understand the ClientSocket instantiation part. Can you explain the (SocketImpl) cast and also the 'implAccept' method? Thanks indeed

Comment: Apologies, I just found the 'implAccept()', makes sense. Thanks!

Comment: I took a copy of the accept() method and made the minimum of changes. Ideally, you could drop the parameter as your constructor doesn't have to be the same as that for Socket.

Comment: Thanks for that. However, I read the implAccept method in ServerSocket and I understand that a ClientSocket instance will be handed to this ServerClientSocket instance. However, I am not sure of the ((SocketImpl) null) part of the above code. Can you explain? Thanks again

Comment: It just calls a constructor which takes (SocketImpl) with a null argument. If you don't have such a constructor, I suggest you use a constructor which calls `super((SocketImpl) null);` so its behaviour is the same.

Comment: So should I add this constructor to my ClientSocket class? such as public ClientSocket(SocketImpl si) { super(si); } Thanks

Comment: That might be simplest. Without looking at your code I couldn't say for sure. Perhaps you can make it protected or package-private. I would look at the code for Socket to give you some ideas.

Comment: Ok, got it. I just setup a no arg constructor in my ClientSocket class that calls 'super();'. Thanks again for all the help.